# Sticky header disappears on scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a page built with the html structure below. My issue is that the sticky header disappears on scroll. [See jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/vecgzd7f/2/).

The issue can be fixed by removing `body {height: 100%}` but I need this property to keep the footer stick to the bottom of the page (using flexbox).
Any idea how I can fix this?

HTML:

```
<header>Sticky header</header>
<main>Main content</main>
<footer>Footer - must stick to bottom at all times</footer>
```

Css:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 0%;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: min-height: 100vh to body (and remove height)

Comment: Yes! Why didn't I think of that. Thank you so much.
Please leave an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the similar properties to the `footer` that you gave to the `header`:

```css
footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/6yhj7p0u/

Comment: Thank you, but it's not quite what I want. In your example the footer is sticky, but it also overlaps the content, which is not what I'm after.

Comment: @Meek In that case, remove the `<footer>` and add CSS for `main {bottom: 0;}`